# android layer list won't show both a gradient and a solid

Tags: android, xml, gradient, layer-list

I don't understand what is going on with this code.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ff8898A4" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#ffD6DDD8"
            android:startColor="#ffB1BBC3" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

If I move the solid below the gradient the gradient doesn't show. But the way it is now the solid won't show. I didn't have any trouble with two solid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are placing the solid shape item over the gradient shape item.

You need to add some padding to the gradient shape. You are doing the opposite adding the padding to the solid shape versus the gradient shape, try this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ff8898A4" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#ffD6DDD8"
            android:startColor="#ffB1BBC3" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I want both. I want a solid line at the bottom of my gradient. that's why the solid line is in an item with a bottom attribute

Comment: See my edits. Basically you are placing the gradient over the solid and then adding padding to the bottom to show the underlying solid color at the bottom. You were adding the padding to the solid shape versus the shape for the gradient

Answer (score 0):

The second rectangle covers the first completely. Items in a layer-list are drawn on top of each other beginning with the first. If the don't have any offset, they all have the same size.

Comment: I think I'm getting my error. So I should draw the solid first and then the gradient with a margin on top.

Thanks both of you.

Comment: or move the bottom offset to the second rectangle